# Why do I have less internal storage space after moving Google+ to my SD card?

Tags: app2sd, internal-storage, google-plus

I'm having a puzzling problem. I was pleased to see that the latest version of Google+ now supports being moved to the SD card.

However, I just installed it on my HTC Desire and, having moved it to the SD card, find I now have 2MB *less* internal storage space on the phone than I did before! Since the previous version was over 12MB, surely the new version should have freed up a significant chunk of internal storage space? I thought this would help address the problem of constantly running low on space, but it seems to have made it worse. Would be grateful for any suggestions / advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version 1.0.7 is *significantly* larger than previous versions. Even after moving to the SD card I'm showing 14.5MB taking up system storage. That'll account for your 2MB reduction in space.

Google generally hasn't allowed for their apps to be moved to the SD card, presumably so they can be sure widgets will work or other performance considerations. However, since this version weighs in at *over* 24MB I guess their hand was forced.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised that Android only moves *part* of the app to the SD card. So any space savings from the moving it to the SD card have been offset by the fact that the new version is just a lot bigger anyway... That would explain it I guess. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: 24 mb? That's insane!

Comment: Huge apps like these are a nightmare for my poor old HTC Magic.

Comment: @SooWeiTan: My Droid isn't much better off.