# Google plus application is 24 mb after wrong update

Tags: updates, internal-storage, google-plus

I was updating from the market this app and I got a package error. I uninstalled it and installed it again from scratch. No problem.
Now the app is 24 mb!
To me it sounds like the broken package is still sitting somewhere in my internal memory...
Cleaning dalvik and application cache didn't help :( 
Any hints?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/why-do-i-have-less-internal-storage-space-after-moving-google-to-my-sd-card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new update has made the size bigger.

Comment: Not possible 24 mb!

Comment: The size may also include your Google Plus data.

Also check the comments at Android Market, there are other people with same issue. For case in point, a guy by the name **Dai** is saying "It says that its 9.77mb but when I download it, it jumped up to 23.something..."

Comment: 8.06 MB for me after install, data is only 180 KB not 16 MB.

Comment: The app most certainly can be 24MB. See this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/why-do-i-have-less-internal-storage-space-after-moving-google-to-my-sd-card

Comment: Can confirm 24MB, just checked my phone and it's 24.34MB/24.27MB/72.0KB (total/applications/data).

Answer (score 0):

Check that the application is only installed once in these directories:

- `/data/app/` for user-installed app directory
- `/system/app/` for pre-installed system app directory

If an app comes preinstalled with the phone or your custom ROM ships with it, then the original .apk will be installed in `/system/app/` (which is read-only, unless you root your phone and remount the directory to be writable) so that you can uninstall the updated version of an app or do a Factory Reset to restore all apps to their original version. This can also happen if you have rooted phone and do an installation by copying an apk to `/data/app`. In short, updated system apps takes double the space than user-installed apps as the system stores the original .apk as well as the updated .apk in separate directory/partition.

If you are 100% sure that you will not downgrade or do a Factory Reset, then you can root the phone and delete `/system/app/BlahBlah.apk` to save some space; although this might not actually give you more space for storing data or applications unless you repartition the internal memory since the `/system/` directory is usually a separate partition from the user-installed app directory. In short, don't do anything unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! It seems I can't find this app :( do you know Google plus app name? Maybe when you update applications their temporary download is stored somewhere else with a different name...